# How can I test teradata odbc?

Tags: odbc, teradata

I installed the teradata client successfully. When I configure the connection I dont see the connection test button.I wrote ip and username and password.
Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the Windows "ODBC Driver Setup" dialog?
There is simply no "test connect" :-)